# unable to attach mongodb _id to html using angularjs and express

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express

I am getting error when attaching `_id` field of MongoDB to html through AngularJS. 
HTML code is as below:

```
<select class="ui search dropdown" name="company" data-value-id="">
                    <option value="">Company</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="company in companies"  data-name="{{company.company_name}}" data-field="{{company._id}}">
                        {{company.company_name}}
                        </option>
                </select>
```

and my AngularJS code which contains an complete collection of MongoDB.

```
$http({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/company/all',
          method: "get",
     }).then(function(data){
        $scope.companies=data.data;
        console.log("company data", data);
     });
```

AngularJS giving me error:

> angular.min.js:83 Error: [$interpolate:interr]

I am getting error only when attaching `_id` to html attributes.
Anyone please solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and ironically, my collection was also named `company`.

In HTML, instead of using `_id`, use simply `id`. It will return a string value of the `ObjectId`.

So your code will be like this:

```
<option ng-repeat="company in companies" data-name="{{company.company_name}}" data-field="{{company.id}}">
```

To see more easily if it's working, try testing it by changing the selection to:

```
{{company.id}}
```

That way you'll be able to see the string value of the `ObjectId` immediately on the combo box.